# LLVM IR : C++ API : Typecast from i1 to i32 and i32 to i1

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, llvm-gcc, llvm-c++-api

I am writing a compiler for a self-made language which can handle only int values i.e. `i32`. Conditions and expressions are similar to C language. Thus, I am considering conditional statements as expressions i.e. they return an int value. They can also be used in expressions e.g `(2 > 1) + (3 > 2)` will return `2`. But LLVM conditions output `i1` value.

- Now, I want that after each conditional statement, `i1` should be converted into `i32`, so that I can carry out binary operations
- Also, I want to use variables and expression results as condition e.g. `if(variable)` or `if(a + b)`. For that I need to convert `i32` to `i1`

At the end, I want a way to typecast from `i1` to `i32` and from `i32` to `i1`. My code is giving these kinds of errors as of now :

For statement like `if(variable)` :

```
error: branch condition must have 'i1' type
br i32 %0, label %ifb, label %else
   ^
```

For statement like `a = b > 3`

```
error: stored value and pointer type do not match
store i1 %gttmp, i32* @a
      ^
```

Any suggestion on how to do that ?

Comment: There is [TruncInst](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1TruncInst.html). I don't have immediate answer, but I would compile a simple program to LLVM IR and see how trunc instruction is used. This simple program must contain the truncation `i32 -> i1`, so that TruncInst is emitted.

Comment: To get the opposite: `i1 -> i32` you most probably need a `CastInst`.

Comment: [IRBuilder::CreateIntCast](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1IRBuilder.html#a31a4dba1bcad1b45216ae48b8c124f20) will create a zext / trunc / bitcast as needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out. To convert from `i1` to `i32`, as pointed out [here by Ismail Badawi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47264133/llvm-ir-c-api-typecast-from-i1-to-i32-and-i32-to-i1#comment81502727_47264133) , I used `IRBuilder::CreateIntCast`. So if `v` is `Value *` pointer pointing to an expression resulting in `i1`, I did following to convert it to `i32` :

```
v = Builder.CreateIntCast(v, Type::getInt32Ty(getGlobalContext()), true);
```

But same can't be applied for converting `i32` to `i1`. It will truncate the value to least significant bit. So `i32 2` will result in `i1 0`. I needed `i1 1` for non-zero `i32`. If `v` is `Value *` pointer pointing to an expression resulting in `i32`, I did following to convert it in `i1` :

```
v = Builder.CreateICmpNE(v, ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(getGlobalContext()), 0, true))
```